# Recursive function with local variable not executing if statement

Tags: java, recursion

```
public int count7(int n) 
{
    int count = 0;
    if (n%10 == 7) count= 1;
    if(n%10 != 7) count= 0;

    if (n < 10 && n==7) return 1;
    if (n < 10 && n!=7) return 0;
    else return count7(n/10) + count;
}
```

I have the above function that recursively adds the occurrences of 7 in the given number. Each time it divides the number by 10 to reduce it by 1 number and checks if the last digit equals 7.

When I run it as count7(7), it returns 1. I have a question regarding why it never hits the first if statement `(if n%10 == 7) count = 1;`

If my program was written as:

```
public int count7(int n) 
{
    int count = 0;
    if (n%10 == 7) count= 0;
    if(n%10 != 7) count= 0;

    if (n < 10 && n==7) return 1;
    if (n < 10 && n!=7) return 0;
    else return count7(n/10) + count;
}
```

The call count7(7) would still work. My question is that as recursive calls are placed on the stack, why is the last call not assign count as 1 and instead assign it 0?

Eg:

Count7(717)

```
Count7(7) + count <-------This hits the base case since n < 10
Count(71) + count
Count(717) + count
```

Count is assigned 1 whenever n % 10 == 7. But the base case also returns 1. Please explain this one case as it is the only thing I am not able to understand properly.

Comment: As an aside "if (n < 10 && n==7)" is redundant.

Comment: Step through the code, line by line. As you go, write the values of each variable on a piece of paper (remembering to keep track of all the different instances of ;'count').

Comment: Does your second code work for count(717)?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine ([demo](http://ideone.com/YJSlzd)).

Comment: Second code does not work for 717. I just wanted to point out that if I ran it with count7(7) it would work even with base case returns 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three return statements in play

```
if (n < 10 && n==7) return 1;
if (n < 10 && n!=7) return 0;
else return count7(n/10) + count;
```

Only the third one (the recursive case) uses the `count` variable at all. When you do `count7(7)`, that triggers the base case immediately, returning 1 without ever caring what `count` is equal to, because that first return statement is used instead of the third, which I imagine is what you're expecting.

Comment: Got it. The first statement is returning 1 without doing anything with count since it never even get's to that point.

Answer (score 2):

**My question is that as recursive calls are placed on the stack, why is the last call not assign count as 1 and instead assign it 0?**

`count` is a local variable and gets set to different values for each call in the stack.  when `n=7`, `if (n < 10 && n==7) return 1;` gets executed and therefore returns 1.

That is why it doesn't matter what the value of `count` is in the base case since the value of `count` is not taken into account in the return.

If you unwind the recursion it becomes

```
count7( 717) =  count(71) +1 
                (count(7) + 0) + 1
                1 + 0 + 1
             --------------
                   2
```

Comment: Incidentally, the code could be simplified if the value of count were used in the base case return.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Going through the code on a piece of paper I drew it out and came by the same thing you posted. It was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Trace the execution of your code. When you call `count7(7)` it does trigger the if statement you point out and set `count = 1`, but the value of `count` is not used afterward. The next statement that executes is `if (n < 10 && n == 7) return 1` which exits the method on the `return` statement. The value of count is not used so the change you made has no effect on the execution of the method.